# Autowire a class which implements Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

I have a service which processes several files in a for loop, file can fall in one of 5 categories and the processing is mostly done via reading file, using a rest call to update some details in a database. Each category has a different rest endpoint and they aren't all that fast.

Code Structure Before: (Single Thread execution)

Parent Class

```java
public class Parent  {

    public static final String SUCCESS_MESSAGE = "Successfully processed your files";
    private static final String SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE = "spring.profiles.active";
    private static final String LINE_SEPERATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    @Autowired
    private ChildService1 childservice1;
    @Autowired
    private ChildService2 childservice2;
    @Autowired
    private ChildService3 childservice3;
    @Autowired
    private ChildService4 childservice4;


    /**
     * The processFiles function is used to process the files downloaded from the FTP server.
     * It checks for all the files in a directory and then processes them accordingly.
     *
     * @return A string
     */
    @Override
    public String processFiles()  {

        for (File file : files) {
          
            try {
                if (file.getName().contains("svalue1))
                    childservice1.processFile(file);
                else if (file.getName().contains("svalue2))
                    childservice2.processFile(file);
                else if (file.getName().contains("value3))
                    childservice3.processFile(file);
                else if (file.getName().contains("value4))
                   childservice4.processFile(file);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Exception occurred when processing file {}, the cause was {}", file.getName(), e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        return SUCCESS_MESSAGE;
    }
```

Child class Structure

```java
@Service
@Slf4j
public class ChildService {
    @Autowired
    private ReadCSVService<ChildServiceCSV> readCSVService;

    @Autowired
    private Mapper mapperUtil;

    @Autowired
    private ChildRepository repository;

    /**
     * The processFile function takes a file as an input and reads the contents of the file.
     * It then maps each line to a ChildServiceCSV object, which is then mapped to
     * a rest call model. The model is then updated in the database using repository's update method
     *
     * @param file Get the absolute path of the file
     * @return Void
     */
    public void processFile(File file) {
        Iterator<ChildServiceCSV> iterator = readCSVService.mapToCSVIterator(file.getAbsolutePath(), ChildServiceCSV.class);
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            ChildServiceCSVcsvModel csvModel = iterator.next();
            RESTModel restModel = mapperUtil.mapCsvModelToMDMModel(csvModel);
            repository.update(restModel );
        }
    }
}
```

So I figured to make this process falster by using`ExecutorService` , create a @Bean  and Autowire it in a the Parent class that has the for loop and then call  processFIle in separate threads.

The issue I'm facing here is a design problem, my method in child services takes the file as an input `processFile(file)`, if I make it implement Runnable how do I call the method that expects file in its argument.

One way would be to create constructor of Child service that takes in file as input and assigns value to a member variable, and then I wouldn't have any problems accessing the variable(file) in my run method, but then I wouldn't be able to Autowire the child service in my Parent class, and would need to create new instances every Time. I need some sort of way to be able to do following

```
for (File file : files) {
      if (file.getName().contains("svalue1))
                    executerService.execute(childservice1.processFile(file));
```

Below I what I was able to implement, need suggestions on how to make this better and use @Autowire with child class while still having this threadPoolExecutor functionality. Thanks.

One possible workaround without auto-Wiring the child classes:

```java
@Bean
public ExecutorService getExecuted(){
   return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
}
```

Parent Class

```
public class Parent  {

   @Autowired
   ExecutorService executorService;

    public String processFiles()  {

        for (File file : files) {
          
                if (file.getName().contains("svalue1))
                    executorService.execute( new ChildService1(file));
               //repeat same for other child services
        }
        executorService.shutDown();
        return SUCCESS_MESSAGE;
    }
```

Child Class

```java
@Service
@Slf4j
public class ChildService implements Runnable {
    @Autowired
    private ReadCSVService<ChildServiceCSV> readCSVService;

    @Autowired
    private Mapper mapperUtil;

    @Autowired
    private ChildRepository repository;

    private File file;

    ChildService (File file){
       this.file=file;
    }

    /**
     * The processFile function takes a file as an input and reads the contents of the file.
     * It then maps each line to a ChildServiceCSV object, which is then mapped to
     * a rest call model. The model is then updated in the database using repository's update method
     *
     * @param file Get the absolute path of the file
     * @return Void
     */
    public void processFile(File file) {
        Iterator<ChildServiceCSV> iterator = readCSVService.mapToCSVIterator(file.getAbsolutePath(), ChildServiceCSV.class);
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            ChildServiceCSVcsvModel csvModel = iterator.next();
            RESTModel restModel = mapperUtil.mapCsvModelToMDMModel(csvModel);
            repository.update(restModel);
        }
    }


   @Override
   public void run() {
      this.processFile(file);
    }


}
```

### Update Solved

Used @EnableAsync and @Async annotation

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class CreateTaskConsoleApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Thread-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
//..... come code here
}
```

used `@Async` on my child class's method, made it return a `CompletableFuture<String>` instead of void.

Added following in parent Class

```
    List<CompletableFuture<String>> futuresList = new ArrayList<>();
     for (File file : files) {
          
            try {
                if (file.getName().contains("svalue1))
                    futuresList.add(childservice1.processFile(file));
                else if (file.getName().contains("svalue2))
                    futuresList.add(childservice2.processFile(file));
                else if (file.getName().contains("value3))
                    futuresList.add(childservice3.processFile(file));
                else if (file.getName().contains("value4))
                    futuresList.add(childservice4.processFile(file));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Exception occurred when processing file {}, the cause was {}", file.getName(), e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        CompletableFuture.allOf(futuresList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futuresList.size()])).join();
        return SUCCESS_MESSAGE;
}
```

Comment: Don't please don't. You are making things overly complex. Use springs async support and annotate the method with `@Async` instead of messing around with the executor yourself. \

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. I went through the spring's tutorial and it'll work like a charm for me.  Thanks again, now I feel like what a dumb question this was :(.